# Reverse geocoding residential addresses within radius

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Given a pair of lat/long coordinates, is anyone aware of an API that would allow me to retrieve all known street addresses within a specified radius? Note that for this particular problem it's a requirement that we start from a lat/long coordinate.

Backstory here is I'm attempting to utilize [Zillow's API](https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/APIOverview.htm) to glean housing valuations for a given area. The best way I can see to accomplish this would be to retrieve a list of address and to provide them individually to their API.

I've played a bit with [Google Map's Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start). In my testing I've found that it only ever gives me a single result with a variable "street_number". So a very precise lat/long pair gives a specific address (202 Main St) whereas a less precise one gives a range (200-299 Main St). The same seems true with [OpenCage's API](https://geocoder.opencagedata.com/api#intro). Obviously what I'm looking for would include multiple streets.

Any thoughts to an API or a different approach I could take to accomplish the problem?

Comment: The best you can do with one data source is the range of addresses -- 
I think the census is where the Google data come from (https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/geocoder.html). *but* if you have the time, the entity that taxes the property will know the specific addresses and I bet most are online. For example you can check the Cook County assessor's page here for any property in Cook County, IL http://www.cookcountyassessor.com/Search/Property-Search.aspx